# capturing standard error stream not working in clojure

Tags: clojure

It is known that you can use the command binding to temporarily attach a custom writer to global vars such as *out*. For example, this works:

```
(let [customWriter (StringWriter.)]
  (binding [*out* customWriter]
    (println "One line!")
    (.toUpperCase (.toString customWriter))))
```

It prints "ONE LINE!\r\n" as expected.

I captured the standard output in my customWriter. I would like to do the same thing with the standard error stream. So I did:

```
(let [customWriter (StringWriter.)]
  (binding [*err* customWriter]
    (try (/ 1 0)
      (catch Exception e
        (.printStackTrace e)
        (.toString customWriter)))))
```

But it returns an empty String and still prints the stack trace in the console. It is funny that if try *err* and System/err in the REPL they are diferent instances.

I know there is another way to do what I want which is to pass a custom PrintWriter to the method printStackTrace of the exception. But I think I misunderstood something related to *err* that I need to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `.printStackTrace` method is agnostic to the existence of Clojure's `*err*` var, so `binding` it won't change Java's behavior.

Consider instead

```
(use 'clojure.stacktrace)

(try (/ 1 0) 
  (catch Exception e 
    (with-out-str (print-stack-trace))))
```

See source of `print-stack-trace` for details, but basically it is using the `.getStackTrace` method and then printing to `*out*`, which you can bind with `with-out-str`, for example.

Comment: This works for things that are aware of `*out*` and `*err*`, but you're out of luck for Java classes that write to System.err directly. For that you'll have to manually call `System/setErr`. At one point I had a macro to nicely wrap that up, but it's probably lost to the sands of time.